# Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender Roundcube Plesk

Tags: email, plesk, roundcube

I have a VPS with Ples. I did the domain configuration and etc. I go to webmail.mydomain.com and login, when I send email to email@hotmail.com the recipient receives it. When I send it to email@gmail.com it returns an error.

The error is as follows:

```
This is the mail system at host xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.138.26]
    said: 550-5.7.26 This message does not have authentication information or
    fails to 550-5.7.26 pass authentication checks. To best protect our users
    from spam, the 550-5.7.26 message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.26
    https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550
    5.7.26 information. a6si7013466oic.272 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA
    command)
Reporting-MTA: dns; xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 4F52C100FA1
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; xxxxx@mydomain.com
Arrival-Date: Sat, 20 Mar 2021 21:44:24 +0000 (UTC)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.26
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.26 This message does not have authentication
    information or fails to 550-5.7.26 pass authentication checks. To best
    protect our users from spam, the 550-5.7.26 message has been blocked.
    Please visit 550-5.7.26
    https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550
    5.7.26 information. a6si7013466oic.272 - gsmtp
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, the error message contains a link to the possible causes.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication

Why is this happening?

Because Gmail doesn't just accept emails from any domain without autheticating them.

Research keywords SPF, DMARC & DKIM. They will lead you in the right path.